# SQL Server: way to see final query with filled parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to see final query which is passed to SQL Server database from my C# app ?

For ex I got query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = @yyyy;
```

This creates and SQLCommand object

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = @yyyy");
```

Plus I need to pass parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@yyyy","MyValue");
```

What I want to see (in debug in C# or somewhere in SQL Server Management Studio) is this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = MyValue
```

Where can I find such query ?!

Best regards

Comment: This question is based on my problem with following query: SELECT * FROM table WHERE x.y = 1 ORDER BY @descOrAsc. Passing SqlParameter("@descOrAsc", "DESC") causes errors ...  (no results) while typing in (... ORDER BY DESC) works fine

Answer (score 6):

> Where can I find such query ?!

You can't. Such a query never exists. The values are *not* substituted into the SQL.

I think actually sp_executesql is called, and this function accepts the parameters separately from the SQL. You can check this using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(v=sql.80).aspx) to see the actual SQL.

---

*Update*:

> ORDER BY @descOrAsc

Your problem is that parameters can only be used in certain places where expressions are allowed. `DESC` is not an expression - it is a reserved word. You cannot use a parameter containing the string `"DESC"` instead of writing the keyword `DESC` in the query.

Also, you haven't specified which column to order by.

Comment: So is there any way of debuging SQL ?!

Comment: @aspnewb: Yes, lots of ways. You can for example start SQL Profiler which allows you to see the SQL.

Comment: And what to do if I need to dynamically change the SQL query to order by random column (Sorting diffrent columns on request etc) ? Concatenate the SQL query ? Is this not a sql injection vulnerable ?

Comment: @aspnewb: Concatenation of constant strings has a very low risk of introducing a vulnerability. It is much less risky than concatenating user provided data.

Comment: Yes, youre right, but user provides sorting column name (as: ... ORDER BY mycolumn1 DESC). "mycolumn1" string comes from javascript, and I cant be sure if is not "malformed". Unless I will introduce my own sanitizer checking for column name ... I just thought there is simpler way

Comment: You could try to organise it in such a way that the column was provided by its index. In your code you would interpret the index and construct the query's ORDER BY bit safely. Another way could be to pass the index to the query itself and have it to order the result set by `CASE @index WHEN 1 THEN Col1 CASE 2 THEN Col2 ... `. Less flexible and less performant, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the SQL Server Profiler and see all the queries that get executed, to see whats happening (and copy paste these into the Sql Server Management Studio to do tests etc)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the query to be passed *to SQL Server* with the parameters. There should be no need for anything to ever create a full SQL-only query. It makes no sense to do so, as it just means more conversions for either the client, the server or both. On the server side, the query processor is going to want to parse the query into clauses with values - if the command can pass those values directly, where's the advantage on converting them into the SQL statement, only to have the server parse them into separate values again?

Comment: But how can you debug sql queries ?!

Comment: @aspnewb: It depends on exactly what you mean. You can use SQL Management Studio to execute ad-hoc queries... I don't know offhand whether you can give that parameterized queries and specify the parameters. I can see that it would be useful to be able to...

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use SQL Profiler. (here you can see all process)
2.You can write all your queries to SQL Server table. And then you can always get queries from this table.